# How to find third coordinate $O(x,y,z)$ on plane $E$ by using two known points, degrees.

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

I'm facing some problems by finding the one missing point on plane $E$. We want to find $O(x,y,z)$ by using two known points $P(2,3,5)$ and $Q(1,2,2)$ and angle of $POQ = 60$ degrees with plane $E: 1.15714286x + 1.8547619y - z -2.86101191 = 0$ and length $OP = OQ$.

Is there any way to find it?

Thank you.

Comment: you have 3 conditions: point $O(x,yz)$ lies on plane $E$, $OP=OQ$ and $\angle POQ=60^{\circ}$. So you will get three equations in three unknowns.

Comment: I try to use the distance equation, I got to from OP and OQ, but those lengths are displayed in the quadratic equation and after that, I subtract it and get one equation. There are only 2 with plane equation. I haven't used a degree in that calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 conditions:

1). point $O(x,yz)$ lies on plane $E$, so
$$ 1.15714286x + 1.8547619y - z =2.86101191$$

2). $OP=OQ$
$$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2+(z-5)^2=(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2.$$
This simplifies to
$$2x+2y+6z=29.$$

3). $\angle POQ=60^{\circ}$ and $OP=OQ$ so $\triangle POQ$ is **equilateral**. Thus
$$OQ^2=PQ^2 \implies (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-2)^2=11.$$

The answer will not be unique.

Comment: But vector(O)⋅vector() = ||OP||.||OQ||.cos60. it still same like equation 2 right ?

Comment: @SamannLong That's right. So instead you use the distance.

Comment: Thank you so much. What if the degrees of that's triangle change? Maybe POQ = 35 degrees instead, i think we need to follow another procedure right? How can we do it ?

Comment: @SamannLong In that case you will have to use angle formula.

Comment: I still confuse with that formula, could you share it again ?

Comment: @SamannLong $\cos \theta=\frac{x \cdot y}{\|x\| \, \|y\|}$.

Comment: The problem I only know, x.y = ||x||.||y|| cos(Delta). is x.y vector can transform to something else ?

Comment: @SamannLong It is the dot product of two vectors.

Comment: I used dot product x.y = x1x2+y1y2+z1z2 but the answer show the same equation as number 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you proceed step by step it is not that hard. From the nature of point $O$, it would lie on the perpendicular bisector of the line $PQ$, which lies in the plane E.

Let us first find this line. For that, we need to know a point through which it passes, and it's direction

1. Point - It passes through the midpoint of PQ - which can be found easily (point $\vec{M}$)
2. Direction - it is a vector perpendicular to the plane normal as well as the direction of line PQ. Hence take the cross product of both of these vector to get the vector of the line $\hat{l}$

Now that we have these two, we can write any point on the line

$$\vec{A} = \vec{M} + \lambda\hat{l}$$

Since the given triangle is iscoceles, you can directly obtain $\lambda$ using some trigonometry with the given angles to find what the length of $\vec{EM}$ would be